# Access to JMeter script path

Tags: java, jmeter

Is there a way of accessing the current script's absolute physical path via a variable/property? There doesn't appear to be anything listed via a Debug Sampler.

It's incredibly annoying that actions like loading CSV files and JMX Includes uses the current working directory as its relative path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller)
  As per component's reference:

  > This element does not support variables/functions in the filename
  >   field.
  >   However, **if the property  includecontroller.prefix  is
  >   defined, the contents are used to prefix the pathname.**  If the file
  >   cannot be found at the location given by prefix+filename, then the
  >   controller attempts to open the fileName relative to the JMX launch
  >   directory (versions of JMeter after 2.3.4).
  >
  > You can pass JMeter a java property named includecontroller.prefix
  >   which can be used to prepend a directory to the JMX file you're
  >   including.

  1) In case of console launch use:



  `-Jincludecontroller.prefix=/full/path/to/jmx/scripts/dir/`



  2) in case of GUI - add the same to .sh/.cmd/.bat file or write a wrapper file;

  3) in case of [Jmeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php) usage - set as separate property:

  ```
  <jmeter 
  jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}" 
  testplan="..." 
  resultlog="...">
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
      <property name="includecontroller.prefix" value="..."/>
  </jmeter>
  ```
- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
  As per component's reference:

  > Relative file names are resolved with respect to the path of the
  >   active test plan.
  >   **Absolute file names are also supported, but note
  >   that they are unlikely to work in remote mode, unless the remote
  >   server has the same directory structure.** If the same physical file is
  >   referenced in two different ways - e.g. csvdata.txt and ./csvdata.txt - then these are > > treated as different files. If the OS does not distinguish between upper 
  >   and lower case, csvData.TXT would also be opened separately.

  You can declare a test plan variable that retrieves parameter value with the folder containing csv data files:

  e.g.

  ```
  csv.path | ${__P(csv.path, ${__property(user.dir)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)})}
  ```

  ```
  CSV Data Set Config
  Filename = ${csv.path}${__P(users-list,)}
  ```

  Setting from console:

  ```
  -Jcsv.path=/full/path/to/csv/data/dir/
  ```

  Setting for distributed testing setup:

  ```
  -Gcsv.path=/full/path/to/csv/data/dir/
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer Alies. How does this work when running in "debug" via the GUI?

Comment: Thanks for the documentation references. I was confused as the log output implies that the JMeter home path was used; however, if the JMX-relative path is correct it will work.

Answer (score 20):

I used the answer provided by haridsv.  It worked great except that I needed to put the directory to the JMX file in a variable.  I made a "User Defined Variables" component and used BeanShell in the variable's "Value" field like this:

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}
```

The first BeanShell section calls the Java class that gets the directory in question.  The second appends a file separator to the path, which is of course optional.

Comment: This works in gui, non-gui and with all components without messing around with configuration or parameters

Comment: Just for the record: An effect of this solution, (at least for 3.2 that I tested), is that for some reason there is no more overwrite warning for report files (Append is automatically performed)

Answer (score 8):

By saying "current script's absolute physical path", I am guessing OP is referring to the location where the testplan (jmx file) is loaded from. I needed exactly this to generate a CSV file from BeanShell script at the beginning of the run, which is subsequently used in a CSV Data Set Config to read back, so I wanted the script to work just like how the later works when no path is specified. I went through the JMeter source and found this working solution:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
log.info(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir());
```

I tested this and saw the correct path in the jmeter.log.

Answer (score 3):

My particular issue was that my relative Include Controller path included a backslash which broke on Linux and OSX.

The solution was to use a forward slash in relative paths, which works on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for that. Inside the jmeter scripts you can also use ${__BeanShell(File.separator,)} to setup all the paths - this will make they platform-independent too.

Comment: @AliesBelik - I'll keep that in mind, though for this case the Include Controller doesn't support variables (as per your answer).

Comment: What does exactly these command mean ?${__BeanShell(Name_Of_BeanShell_Script)}. I've a beanshell scripts inside my jMeterProject and I would like to use only one of it before sending request. Should I use inside BeanShell PreProcessor command:
${__BeanShell(Name_of_my_script)}??