# How to get directory of jmeter script in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a custom jmeter sampler written in java that takes file location and file path as parameters and based on those creates a json file for posting to a service (based on a template file). Since my script needs to run on multiple environments with varying directory structures, I need to use a relative path in my sampler to point to the file I need to translate into valid json. Is there a way to get the directory my script lives in as a variable in jmeter? I have tried ${user.dir}, but that returns the directory where jmeter launched from, not the directory where my script lives. Is there another system property I could reference to get this value? If not, has anyone programmatically accomplished this?

Comment: have you tried any of the solutions listed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179463/access-to-jmeter-script-path ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I ran into a similar situation a while ago where I had to upload a signature file as part of a POST request. This signature file lived relative to the folder structure in which my JMeter scripts were located.

Try using the following BeanShell expression (which can be accessed as a system-level property) to resolve the relative path from the location in which your JMeter test-cases are located/executed.

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}
```

- You can enter this with the name of the file you want to send/POST in the "Send Files With the Request" field by simply appending the file name.

  `${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}fileName.sig`
- A more cleaner implementation would be declare this as a variable (local or global depending on the scope) and use this variable within the appropriate fields.

  `absolutePath = ${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}`

  `${absolutePath}fileName.sig`

***NOTE:** This approach is super useful if you intend to plug your JMeter test files into a Continuous Integration system such as Jenkins. It makes your test-cases more maintainable.*

Comment: Am getting the path of the file via the given syntax(Say: C:\Users\test.xlsx) and stored in the variable. But when I used the same variable in Java I/O class files(FileInputStream) to read the contents am getting errors. When i debug found the backward slash issue. Couldn't able to pass the same variable to the FileInputStream class. Is there any approach to change the file separator to forward slash?

Comment: str = str.replace("\\", "/"); ?

Comment: That's a great method. I didn't know you can declare a `user defined variable` like that.

Comment: str = str.replace("\\\\", "/");

Comment: ...but I do not see, how to apply this on a UDV, i.e. ${user.dir}.
Any help, to finish this thread?

Comment: If you're running JMeter distributed: note that this doesn't provide the same path when running JMeter distributed on a Windows platform. The JMeter nodes will report for getBaseDir() the local path where jmeter-server was run from with a trailing period (e.g. "C:\apps\JMeter-5.3-Server\bin\."), rather than the path where the .jmx file is loaded from.

Comment: This seems to work: `${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir().replace("\\\\"\, "/");)}`