# JMeter Script Path missing "\" so not working?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to use the beanshell script posted here to get the path of the jmx that is being run in my jmeter test - [Access to JMeter script path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179463/access-to-jmeter-script-path)

It is working and if I log the output of the path when set by beanshell or view the variables with the debugger I get the path to the script displayed as I expected -

```
c:\my\path\to\script
```

but when I then try to pass that variable into sendKeys, the slashes "\" are being removed so -

```
c:mypathtoscript
```

And this doesn't work so I am unable to attach/upload my file..

Sure I am missing something stupid

Thanks

Comment: try escaping the backward slashes.

Comment: Hi Kevin, How can I do that? the path is being generated by the beanshell script that is posted in the link...

Comment: i don't know how you would escape the generated path, but use either double backslash to escape a backslash or a forward slash if you can modify it before it gets passed to your sendKeys variable.

Comment: please share the BeanShell code and how you are passing the value of JMeter absolute path

Comment: I have a UDV called "homepath" with a value of "${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}" and I am calling the variable using ${homepath}, debug shows it with single backslash, and these are being removed when webdriver runs..

Answer (score 0):

Needed to user vars.put to put the JMeter UDV value into a Javascript variable, then use javascript concatenate to link it all together.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to get this done without using Beanshell:

1. Call [FileServer](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html) methods from WebDriver Sampler:

   ```
   someElement.sendKeys(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir())
   ```
2. Get the value from [JMeterVariables](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)

   ```
   var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
   someElement.sendKeys(vars.get('homepath'))
   ```

Example full code:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://ya.ru')
var searchInput = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('text'))

//directly access function from JavaScript
searchInput.sendKeys(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir())

//alternative way - getting the value from JMeter Variables
var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
searchInput.sendKeys(vars.get('homepath'))

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Comprehensive information on accessing JMeter API classes from WebDriver Sampler and few more tips and tricks: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Comment: You do the same twice: You manipulate Files. But the original question is asking how to manipulate Strings, so not to loose the backslashes.